# When I am running my showLocation function 5 times, I get nothing as a response

Tags: c++, class, constructor, scope, default-constructor

so when i run this program,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

float ex, ey;

class Enemy
{
    public:
        float x, y;
    
        Enemy()
        {
            x = ex;
            y = ey;
        }
    
        void showLocation()
        {
            std::cout<<x<<" , "<<y<<std::endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    Enemy e;
    for(int i = 0;i<5,i++;)
    {
        ex = rand() % 5 + 1;
        ey = rand() % 5 + 1;
        e.showLocation();
    }
}
```

I get nothing, am I doing something wrong?
I get a blank space, then it says, "Process exited - return code 0"

Comment: Typo: `for(int i = 0;i<5,i++;)` --> `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` There are other "issues" but that's the main one.

Comment: `x = ex` doesn't estabilish any kind of permanent binding between `ex` and `x`. They remain separate variables.

Comment: Recommendation:  <expletive deleted> the global variables. Globals may make your code easier to write, but they have an annoying tendency to make a program disproportionately harder to debug, and debugging is almost always harder and more time consuming than writing the program. Make a smarter constructor for `Enemy` that accepts `ex` and `ey` as parameters, `Enemy(float ex, float ey): x(ex), y(ey) { }` and then `Enemy e(rand() % 5 + 1, rand() % 5 + 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

The object `e` is initialized before the for loop. So its data members `x` and `y` are set equal to `0.0f` (the global variables `ex` and `ey` are implicitly zero initialized) by the default constructor and are not changed any more.

```
Enemy e;
for(int i = 0;i<5,i++;)
{
    ex = rand() % 5 + 1;
    ey = rand() % 5 + 1;
    e.showLocation();
}
```

You need to declare the object in the for loop for example like

```
for(int i = 0;i<5,i++;)
{
    ex = rand() % 5 + 1;
    ey = rand() % 5 + 1;
    Enemy e;
    e.showLocation();
}
```

In this case in each iteration of the for loop there will be created a new object `e` data members of which will be initialized by calculated  values of the global variables `ex` and `ey`.